# How to remove empty space in Avada WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I remove the built-in blank space below the header?
The theme is Avada
[image: The extra space is marked with a blue line]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to remove the built-in blank space below the header you should this css of code:

```
#main {
       padding-top: 0;
    }
    
    .header-avada {
       margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```